# How to handle Twilio Programmable Voice token limits and multiple tab usage in web applications?

Tags: twilio

We have integrated Twilio Programmable Voice into our application, where access tokens are generated for users using their user IDs as identities. According to the Twilio documentation (https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens), Programmable Voice access tokens have a limit of ten concurrent sessions for a given identity. When the 11th instance of the identity is registered, the oldest registration is automatically removed.

Our application allows users to log in via both mobile and web platforms. When a user receives a call, it should ring on both the web and mobile phones simultaneously.

However, we've encountered an issue with users who tend to open multiple tabs in our web application. When a user exceeds ten tabs and leaves their desk, if an incoming call occurs, the mobile device stops receiving the call. This leads to user dissatisfaction and complaints.

What would be the best approach to resolve this issue and ensure that incoming calls are reliably received on both web and mobile devices, even when users have multiple tabs open in the web application? Any insights or suggestions on how to effectively manage Twilio token limits and handle multiple tab usage in web applications would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.